# How to run Javascript and jQuery in Firefox on an external web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, firefox

I want to run my own JavaScript (written using jQuery) in Firefox in an external web page. How to do that?

I know it can be done by jQuerify and ScratchPad. But I have a loop running and new page would be loaded. So, I can't click the jQuerify button every time. So, is there any fixed way of having jQuery integrated so that I can write the JavaScript and simulate?

Comment: Yes, include jQuery and your external JS file in your page via `<script>` tags. Look at the source of virtually any website to figure out how this is done.

Comment: I want to run my code on an external webpage to manipulate it. I can't include anything to them.

Comment: what is an external webpage? do you want to execute your own javascript in a page you can't control? do you want to do some cross-site scripting 0_o ?

Comment: Yes. Because, it has lot of data. And I want to manipulate them.

Comment: You can use a iFrame (yuck) then inject your script inside but you will have some browser security to bypass. And jQuery events have a lot of issues when injected from outside

Comment: Yeah! Then I have to make an internal webpage and load jQuery and write my own Javascript there. But the external web-page can't be loaded in the iframe because they have javascript to prevent loading it in an iframe!! :(

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @robertc suggested, Greasemonkey can be the only solution.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/